# Know if my item is the latest - Owl Carousel

Tags: javascript, jquery, owl-carousel

I would like to know if it is possible to know if my owl-carousel is on the end of the list to disable the `next` button.

Here is my Javascript:

```
 <script>

        $(document).ready(function() {

            var owl = $("#owl");

            owl.owlCarousel({
                items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
                itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
                itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
                itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
                itemsMobile : false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
            });

            // Custom Navigation Events
            $(".next").click(function(){
                owl.trigger('owl.next');
                if(owl.)
            })
            $(".prev").click(function(){
                owl.trigger('owl.prev');
            })
            $(".play").click(function(){
                owl.trigger('owl.play',1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
            })
            $(".stop").click(function(){
                owl.trigger('owl.stop');
            })

        });

    </script>
```

Here is my HTML:

```
<div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="row contracts" rv-show="context:contracts | length | gt 1">
                    <div class="col-sm-12 box box-flex" rv-slide="context:stepHide" style="">
                        <ul id="owl">
                            <li class="col-xs-2">987456</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">558745</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">126985</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">598746</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">325478</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">987652</li><li class="col-xs-2">126985</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">598746</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">325478</li>
                            <li class="col-xs-2">987652</li>
                        </ul>
                    </div>
                </div>
            </div>
            <div class="col-xs-6">
                <div class="customNavigation">
                    <a class="btn prev">Previous</a>
                    <a class="btn next">Next</a>
                    <a class="btn play">Autoplay</a>
                    <a class="btn stop">Stop</a>
                </div>
            </div>

        </div>

    </div>

</div>
```

So when the last `li` item is showed, I want to disable next button.
I searched into Owl functions but I didn't find something as I want.

Thank you

Comment: I dont know about own carousel but after googling, you can combine `afterAction` option and `currentItem` function like [this](http://owlgraphic.com/owlcarousel/demos/owlStatus.html)

Comment: I'll try with it, thank you!

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can do this with cominaison of `afterAction` and `currentItem` like this

```
<script>

$(document).ready(function() {

    var owl = $("#owl");

    owl.owlCarousel({
        items : 5, //10 items above 1000px browser width
        itemsDesktop : [1000,5], //5 items between 1000px and 901px
        itemsDesktopSmall : [900,3], // betweem 900px and 601px
        itemsTablet: [600,2], //2 items between 600 and 0
        itemsMobile : false, // itemsMobile disabled - inherit from itemsTablet option
        afterAction: function() {
             if(this.owl.currentItem == $(owl).children().length - 1) {
                 $('.btn .next').hide();
             } else {
                 $('.btn .next').show();
             }
        },
    });

    // Custom Navigation Events
    $(".next").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.next');
        if(owl.)
    })
    $(".prev").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.prev');
    })
    $(".play").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.play',1000); //owl.play event accept autoPlay speed as second parameter
    })
    $(".stop").click(function(){
        owl.trigger('owl.stop');
    })

});

</script>
```